# Bind reverse ipv6 mapping, dig gives no answer, SERVFAIL

Tags: bind, ipv6, dig, fedora

I am using Fedora 17 with Bind 9 installed, trying to configure a DNS and I already solved a problem:

[Bind DNS configuration, dig command don't resolve name](https://serverfault.com/questions/491272/bind-dns-configuration-dig-command-dont-resolve-name)

Now ipv4 and ipv6 mapping works, also reverse ipv4 mapping works, but the problem is with reverse ipv6. In my named.conf file there is this zone:

```
zone "3.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2.ip6.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "reverse6.zone";
};
```

And this is the reverse6.zone file:

```
$TTL 48h
$ORIGIN 3.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2.ip6.arpa.
@       IN      SOA     gruppo13.labreti.it. master.gruppo13.labreti.it. (
    2013032511
    1d
    2h
    4w
    1h
)
    IN      NS      gruppo13.labreti.it.
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0 IN  PTR gruppo13.labreti.it.
2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0 IN  PTR dns.gruppo13.labreti.it.
8.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0 IN  PTR www.gruppo13.labreti.it.
3.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0 IN  PTR mail.gruppo13.labreti.it.
```

With dig I am able to find an ip6 address, but if I do the reverse:

```
$ dig -x AAAA 2000:0:d::1
```

I don't get answer, and this is the dig output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-rl.028.23-P1-RedHat-9.9.2-5.P1.fc17 <<>> -x AAAA 2000:0:d::1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 43454
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;AAAA.in-addr.arpa.     IN  PTR

;; Query time: 17 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.13.100#53(192.168.13.100)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 26 14:02:39 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 17670
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;2000:0:d::1.           IN  A

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.13.100#53(192.168.13.100)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 26 14:02:39 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40
```

Comment: You're not looking up an address within the zone you specified (which is also an invalid IPv6 network). If you obscured something, please edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command is invalid. You are looking up the inverse of `AAAA`:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;AAAA.in-addr.arpa.     IN  PTR
```

and the IPv4 address of `2000:0:d::1`:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;2000:0:d::1.           IN  A
```

What you want is to drop the `AAAA` from your command (and fix the address):

```
dig -x 2000:0:13::1
```

Which will send the right question:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.3.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2.ip6.arpa. IN PTR
```

And remember that `2000:0:13::1` ≠ `2000:0:d::1`!